# connect to server ( PG:Error ) after bundle install on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I got a very odd bug. In my Rails gem file, I have:

```
gem 'pg'
```

the server can start successfully at this moment. Stop the server and I comment out the pg gem as

```
# gem 'pg'
```

and bundle install. Then I uncomment it and do bundle install. I expected nothing changed, right? But now the server can't start and shows the error:

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied (PG::Error)
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I repeated this several times and got the consistent results. Why would it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add host:localhost, port:5432 fixed the problem. Still don't know why though